# wpf window.open, hide window when main view clicked

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and have two windows in a solution. Both are opened using Window.Open().

However there is a difference in behaviour that I don't understand. When one of the windows is opened, if you click the view that launched it the new window is minimised behind the main view, so you can interact with it.

The other window, when opened and you click the main view stays where it is and does not get hidden.

How can I get this window to show the same behaviour as the first?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, by removing the parent child relationship in the window I was able to get the functionality I desired.